# Maven run ant builds in subdirectories

Tags: ant, maven, war

I have multiple JavaFX 2.0 apps (built with the default ant scripts generated by netbeans 7.0) which I want to be wrapped up into a war by a maven pom in the parent directory.

The war-building pom has lots of ant tasks in the compile phase that look like this:

```
<ant antfile="FXapplication1/build.xml" target="jar"/>
```

But when I go to run 'mvn compile', I get this error from ant:

"C:\path\to\warbuilder\FXapplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:209: Must set src.dir"

The ant script builds fine when explicitly called inside its own directory, so I'm assuming that the problem is that it's looking in the war builder's local directory for its source files, rather than looking for them relative to the build.xml. Is there a way to specify a working path for a given ant task?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113528/axis2-web-service-deploying-by-netbeans-6-8-build-impl-xml166-error

Answer (score 0):

Try making the JavaFX apps modules of the warbuilder app, each with their own pom which executes `<ant antfile="build.xml" target="jar"/>`,
rather than running `<ant antfile="FXapplication1/build.xml" target="jar"/>` from the parent.
The parent should list the children as modules, they will then be executed as part of the parent build process.