# Axis2 web service deploying by Netbeans 6.8 build-impl.xml:166 error

Tags: netbeans, apache-axis, deploying

I tried to create a simple web service using Axis2 + Tom cat + Netbeans 6.8 like this tutorial.

http://netbeans.org/kb/69/websvc/gs-axis.html#deploy_axis

but after all configured as it says and when developing it gives this error:

E:\WorkDesk\Java Projects\MyWebservice\MyWebservice\nbproject\build-impl.xml:166: Must set src.dir
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

please help me out to fix this bug. thanks lot.

Comment: 1) it sounds like an "ant" problem *building* your project (vs. an Axis2 or Tomcat problem actually *running* the project).  I only mention it because knowing it's a "build" problem might simplify troubleshooting.  2) Do you have an ant "build.xml" file in your project?  Does it have an entry for "src.dir"?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Yes there is a build.xml in my netbeans project file. I don't know is it an ant "buil.xml" file because it creates default by netbeans. I think netbeans automatically deploy the this web project. Here is the content of the build.xml:  <project name="MyWebservice" default="default" basedir="C:/Users/daz/.netbeans/6.8/apache-tomcat-6.0.20_base">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project MyWebservice.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/></project>  Do I need to install ant??

Answer (score 0):

For us, the project.properties was not being created properly, which is where src.dir is defined. Deleting the file then rerunning ant fixed the problem.